# Nested UIScrollViews and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have seen several similar issues here in **StackOverflow** regarding `UIScrollView` and `AutoLayout` but now is my turn because I can't make it work properly.

My idea is to have an inner `UIScrollView` that scrolls horizontally (contains a set of images) and an outer `UIScrollView` that apart from the inner above, contains multiple `UILabel`, `UITextView` objects and scrolls vertically.

Without `AutoLayout` both are acting like expected but unfortunately size and origin are not right. With `AutoLayout`, outer `UIScrollView`, scrolls a bit but inner not moving at all. I can confirm that inner `UIScrollView` has the correct `ContentSize` during `viewDidLoad` but later in code has 0,0.

Below is a screenshot with views and associated `Constrains`.

[image]

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

For others who may face the same problem as mine.
In my case seems that the `UIPageControl` was messing up the whole thing. As you can see in the screenshot, I had the pager as a subview of the inner `UISrollView` **WRONG!!!**

I've simply move out the `UIPageControl` (became subview of the outer) and left Xcode to do the rest (Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Add Missing Constrains In View Controller). After that, `UIScrollView`s took tare of their selves (as Apple states in documentation). I've spent so many hours on this. I hope my solution saves others' time.

*I am working on Xcode5*

Answer (score 0):

I've solved UIScrollView content issues with 2 steps:

1. Select UIScrollView, go to Editor>Resolve Auto Layout Issues>Add missing constraints
2. Add a IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint for the height of whatever you are going to put inside the UIScrollView e.g. UIWebView. Hook up this outlet to the Height constraint you add via storyboard.

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

//set the constant to the element once it has been drawn

self.heightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes no difference. By the way, way to set up a property for height when my `UIScrollView` scrolls horizontally?